# Java6, JBoss5, Jersey2.6, Servlet-Container2.5 -> interface org.glassfish.jersey.internal.spi.AutoDiscoverable could not be instantiated: null

Tags: java, web-services, jersey-2.0, jboss5.x

I moved an EAR from one JBoss 5.1 Server to another, I copied the server before. Everything worked fine on the old one, now I get this error and I don't understand, what it tries to tell me:

> [[/KD-Dokumente]] StandardWrapper.Throwable
>   org.glassfish.jersey.internal.ServiceConfigurationError:
>   org.glassfish.jersey.internal.spi.AutoDiscoverable: The class
>   org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.monitoring.MonitoringAutodiscoverable
>   implementing provider interface
>   org.glassfish.jersey.internal.spi.AutoDiscoverable could not be
>   instantiated: null    at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.internal.ServiceFinder.fail(ServiceFinder.java:397)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.internal.ServiceFinder.access$700(ServiceFinder.java:153)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.internal.ServiceFinder$LazyObjectIterator.hasNext(ServiceFinder.java:711)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.internal.ServiceFinderBinder.configure(ServiceFinderBinder.java:68)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.binding.AbstractBinder.bind(AbstractBinder.java:171)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.binding.AbstractBinder.install(AbstractBinder.java:315)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerBinder.configure(ServerBinder.java:109)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.binding.AbstractBinder.bind(AbstractBinder.java:171)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Injections.bind(Injections.java:157)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Injections._createLocator(Injections.java:147)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Injections.createLocator(Injections.java:137)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.(ApplicationHandler.java:265)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.(WebComponent.java:262)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:167)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:349)
>     at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:244)   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1048)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:777)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:129)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
>     at
>   org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:190)
>     at
>   org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:92)
>     at
>   org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.process(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:126)
>     at
>   org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.invoke(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:70)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
>     at
>   org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:158)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:330)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:829)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:598)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:447)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) Caused by:
>   java.lang.ClassCastException  at java.lang.Class.cast(Class.java:2999)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.internal.ServiceFinder$LazyObjectIterator.hasNext(ServiceFinder.java:654)
>     ... 30 more 14:29:59,214 ERROR [[KD-Dokumente]] Allocate exception
>   for servlet KD-Dokumente java.lang.ClassCastException     at
>   java.lang.Class.cast(Class.java:2999)     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.internal.ServiceFinder$LazyObjectIterator.hasNext(ServiceFinder.java:654)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.internal.ServiceFinderBinder.configure(ServiceFinderBinder.java:68)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.binding.AbstractBinder.bind(AbstractBinder.java:171)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.binding.AbstractBinder.install(AbstractBinder.java:315)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerBinder.configure(ServerBinder.java:109)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.binding.AbstractBinder.bind(AbstractBinder.java:171)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Injections.bind(Injections.java:157)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Injections._createLocator(Injections.java:147)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Injections.createLocator(Injections.java:137)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.(ApplicationHandler.java:265)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.(WebComponent.java:262)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:167)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:349)
>     at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:244)   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1048)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:777)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:129)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
>     at
>   org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:190)
>     at
>   org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:92)
>     at
>   org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.process(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:126)
>     at
>   org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.invoke(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:70)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
>     at
>   org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:158)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:330)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:829)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:598)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:447)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)

I would be glad if someone could translate it, I can imagine that a dependency is missing because it says 'provider interface org.glassfish.jersey.internal.spi.Auto Discoverable could not be instantiated: null', so if something is null, it isn't there.

My web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
    <display-name>KD-Dokumente</display-name>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>KD-Dokumente</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
            <param-value>de.pax.kd.webservice.REST</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>KD-Dokumente</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

and my application class:

```
public class REST extends Application {

    private TimerTask cloudWatchService = new CloudWatchService();
    private Timer timer = new Timer();
    private final static int oneSecond = 1000;
    private final static int oneMinute = oneSecond * 60;

    public REST() {
        timer.schedule(cloudWatchService, oneSecond * 3, oneMinute);
    }

    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        final Set<Class<?>> resources = new HashSet<Class<?>>();

        // Add your resources.
        resources.add(Versand.class);

        return resources;
    }
}
```

Thank you.